# JBuilder and Java 5

Tags: java, jbuilder

I'm using JBuilder 6 and running against Java 1.3

I'm migrating to Java 5

Do I need a more modern version of JBuilder to run against Java 5?

Comment: LOL. Have you been cryogenized all these years? >:) And BTW, Java 5 reached EOL. Maybe consider migrating to Java 6 instead.

Comment: I maintain one very old Java application that needs to be migrated. I see JBuilder is not dead though.

Comment: And since you asked, I was cryogenized in 2003 for a crime that I did not commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Primarily to support the syntax sugar added in Java 5 like Generics and the enhanced for loop.

Comment: But if I'm migrating an application that does not use these features could I get away with it